# Run a subshell as root

Tags: bash, security, subshell, privilege-elevation

Consider you have a Linux/UNIX machine with Bash. You have a file **secret.txt** that only root can read.  You want to use a command that takes a string as an argument, say,

```
sample-command <string>
```

Log in as a root user and run the command using the first line of the text file:

```
root ~ $ sample-command $(sed '1!d' secret.txt)
```

Can this be done by non-root, sudoer users?

*Note.* `sudo sh -c "<command>"` doesn't help since subshells don't carry over the root/sudo privilege. For example,

```
sarah ~ $ sudo sh -c "echo $(whoami)"
```

gives you `sarah`, not `root`.

Comment: maybe try `sudo bash -pc command` to launch bash in privileged mode? Also what’s wrong with `$(sudo sed ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) like [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) will be processed by the shell before executing the actual command line:

```
sudo sh -c "echo $(whoami)"
foouser
```

Here the shell will first run `whoami`, as the current user, replace the expansion by it's result and then execute

```
sudo sh -c "echo foouser"
```

---

Expansions doesn't happen within single quotes:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "$(whoami)"'
root
```

In this example `$(whoami)` won't get processed by calling shell because it appears within single quotes. `$(whoami)` will therefore get expanded by subshell before calling echo.

Comment: In this case can you use single quotes in the command next to sh -c? For example, what would you do if you want to use single quotes in arg1 in ``sudo sh -c 'sample-commnd arg1 arg2 ...'`` ?

Comment: You would have to escape them, like `sudo sh -c 'command '\''arg1'\' ...'`. Probably it would be better to just create a shellscript, save it to a file and then run `sudo bash file.sh`. In that shellscript, since you are running it as root, you can just access the secrets.txt, without further tricks

Comment: A side note on hek2mgl's comment above: To understand the ``'\''`` stuff go to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell and see kenorb's answer.

Comment: @Culip It's very good that you think about quoting, and not just omit it because it's painful here!! Doing this consequently will save you many headaches with shellscripting